# how to use return in Python

Tags: python

Is there any difference between these two sample functions, performance-wise? If yes, why?

```
def func(a):
    if a > 0:
        num = 1
    else:
        num = -1
    return num
```

and

```
def func(a):
    if a > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

Comment: I would prefer `return 1 if a > 0 else -1`

Comment: Is this really the bottleneck?

Comment: For all practical purposes, the answer is No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're really interested, you can get an idea of how fast a function will run using `dis`; more lines is probably worse:

`return` at end:

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>) 
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       21 

  5          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1) 
             15 STORE_FAST               1 (num) 
             18 JUMP_FORWARD             6 (to 27) 

  7     >>   21 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1) 
             24 STORE_FAST               1 (num) 

  8     >>   27 LOAD_FAST                1 (num) 
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

11 lines, pretty fast.

`return` in `if`:

```
 13           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>) 
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16 

 14          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1) 
             15 RETURN_VALUE         

 16     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1) 
             19 RETURN_VALUE         
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

10 lines, probably slightly faster.

And thefourtheye's suggestion:

```
def func(a):
    return 1 if a > 0 else -1
```

Gives:

```
 21           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>) 
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16 

 22          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1) 
             15 RETURN_VALUE         

 23     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1) 
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

8 lines, winner (by two lines that will never run)!

But this is *definitely* the premature optimisation your mother warned you about!

Comment: As a question, is there some way in which the 3 methods are not equivalent in terms of possible outcomes in edge-cases that I'm not seeing?  If not, why doesn't Python translate them into the same - um, whatever intermediate form Python translates into?  I always thought if you did something like this on with a modern C compiler it was (theoretically) intelligent enough to compile functionally equivalent code into the same assembly code, and the fastest at that.

Comment: Premature optimization :') Haven't heard that in such a long time... 80-20 rule all the way! (20% of your code run 80% of the time; as long as they are fast, don't care about the rest).

Comment: A C compiler would probably optimize the hell out of that function, it would probably make it inline, even. But then Python is not C and isn't fast anyway, but the main point probably is that Python is either interpreted or JIT compiled at runtime. That doesn't leave too much time for heave optimization.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know dis exist!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my analysis:

**A. Time complexity both are same** :

```
func1          2011 function calls in 0.001 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 fun.py:28(<lambda>)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fun.py:5(func1)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
func2          2011 function calls in 0.001 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fun.py:13(func2)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 fun.py:28(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
```

**B. Space: 2nd function is better:**

```
Filename: fun.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4      8.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
     5                             def func1(a):
     6      8.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       if a > 0:
     7      8.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           num = 1
     8                                 else:
     9                                     num = -1
    10      8.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       return num


1
Filename: fun.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    12      8.2 MiB      0.0 MiB   @profile
    13                             def func2(a):
    14      8.2 MiB      0.0 MiB       if a > 0:
    15      8.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           return 1
    16                                 else:
    17                                     return -1


1
```

C. Here is the bytecode by disassembling it:

```
func1
  6           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       21

  7          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             15 STORE_FAST               1 (num)
             18 JUMP_FORWARD             6 (to 27)

  9     >>   21 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             24 STORE_FAST               1 (num)

 10     >>   27 LOAD_FAST                1 (num)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
None
func2
 14           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

 15          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             15 RETURN_VALUE

 17     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Conclusion: I will choose 2nd one.

Comment: I am using the following module :  cProfile, Timer, dis and profile

Answer (score 2):

There may be a minuscule difference in that the act of assigning a value to `num` is a step that can be bypassed by returning that value directly.  I wouldn't recommend worrying about performance differences of this degree; instead, worry about code readability.  I prefer the second example on readability grounds, but if you disagree, go with whichever you find is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is very slightly faster in that it does not create a new variable and then return that value later on. The return ends the function's control straightaway and returns a value without having to go through the rest of the function's code.

The first method however is slightly slower since it creates the variable `num` and then proceeds through more of the code until the final return value where `num` is referenced again and returned.

Although as @SukritKalra said, if this is bottlenecking your performance, props to you for a highly efficient script.

```
f2 --> Without num
f1 --> With num

f2(1) --> 4.812 e-06 seconds
f2(0) --> 4.812 e-06 seconds
f1(1) --> 6.256 e-06 seconds
f1(0) --> 4.812 e-06 seconds
```

Hardly any difference.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, Right. Sorry. Mixed up the variables.